# How to make <?php include_once('my_username_here.txt'); ?> with with <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?>?

Tags: php, txt

On the welcome page after the user has signed in, if I add this line of code `<?php include_once('my_username_here.txt'); ?>`  and I replace “my_username_here.txt” with “john.txt”, it pulls what is saved on john.txt and shows it on the welcome page.

When I add this line of code `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?>` into this line of code like this `<?php include_once(<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?>.txt'); ?>` it does not work. I have looked high and low and tried different ways and noting seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly so all you need is to edit it like this

```php
<?php 
   include_once(htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]) . '.txt'); 
?>
```

or for simplification, you could edit it like this one

```php
<?php 
   $file_name = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]) . '.txt';
   include_once($file_name); 
?>
```